# How to define objects in discord.py rewrite

Tags: python-3.x, discord, discord.py

As stated in the title, how? I'm really struggling with understanding the documentation as there are no examples of anything. How do I define something like a VoiceState, Member, VoiceChannel, etc...

Running on tutorials is fine until you have to start consulting the documentation for something specific, at which point it becomes really frustrating when you have no idea how to define objects or use certain commands...

Comment: You usually don't create your own model objects.  Instead, you get them from other model objects.  For example, to get a `Member` object using their id, you would do `ctx.guild.get_member(id)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A lot of this will come from experience, so don't be discouraged if it takes a while to get the hang of! I know that the docs can be a bit daunting, but I'll try to help as best I can by giving a couple of examples.

When making a discord bot, usually you're going to be getting information based off of arguments and [`ctx` (context)](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#context).

First I'll start off with some general examples, and then I'll move onto how to use these when working with d.py.

---

## Parameters and args

When you create functions in python, you can define parameter types:

```py
def my_func(a: int):
    return a + 5
```

What this does is assume that the args passed into `my_func` will be integers, and therefore behave as `int`s too:

```py
my_func(1)
```

Will return, as you might expect, `6`.

However, when you try to pass in something like so:

```py
my_func("1")
```

You'll get a `TypeError` which complains about concatenating str and int. Additionally, you can see the differences in an object when you list its attributes like so: `dir(obj)`
When applying this same concept to a command:

```py
@bot.command()
async def cmd(ctx, member: discord.Member):
    await ctx.send(f"Hello, {member.mention}!")
```

But when using commands, what it does is it's able to get a member based off of an attribute you enter, such as the member's ID or name. The member that it finds, then has all of the [`discord.Member`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Member) object's attributes.

This means you'll be able to access things such as the member's [roles](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Member.roles), which return a list containing each role as a [`discord.Role`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Role) object, which from there, you can get the role's attributes, and so on and so forth.

**SIDE-NOTE:**
Another way of getting objects in d.py is by using [`discord.utils`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#utility-functions). It takes in an iterable, e.g. a list, as the first argument, and then after that it takes keyword arguments, such as `name`, `id`, `colour`, or any attributes of an [`abc`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#abstract-base-classes) to return an object.

Example:

```py
@bot.command()
async def getrole(ctx):
    role = discord.utils.get(ctx.author.roles, name="Very Special Role!", mentionable=True)
    await ctx.send(f"Look at you with your {role.mention} How classy!")
```

And that will iterate through each of the message sender's roles, looking for the name (case sensitive) `Very Special Role!` which is mentionable, and it will send the message using one of the role's attributes; [`mention`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Role.mention).

---

## Context

With commands, the first argument you're going to be passing in is [Context](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#context), which by convention is denoted as `ctx`.

As shown in the link, it has a range of attributes, which revolve mostly around the command's origin, author, and all other details about it etc.

```py
@bot.command()
async def hello(ctx):
    await ctx.send(f"Hello, {ctx.author.name}!")
```

In the command there, I'm using the [coroutine](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#coroutines) from context called [`send()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Context.send), which is used for sending messages.

And in the *context* of the command, it'll be sending it to the same channel, which is how that works.

Also, an example of some commonly used superfluous code:

```py
ctx.message.channel.send("some message")
ctx.message.author.send("some dm")
```

can be respectively turned into:

```py
ctx.send("some message")
ctx.author.send("some dm")
```

But how do you know where you can `send()` a message to? Well that brings us onto the next part:

---

## Abstract Base Classes

These are, what I'm assuming you were talking about when you were on about defining objects. They are the base templates for objects to inherit from - for example, [`TextChannel`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.TextChannel) has inherited all of `Messageable`'s attributes (except `connectable`, which is only inherited by [`discord.VoiceChannel.channel`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.VoiceClient.channel).

I'll use [`abc.Messageable`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.abc.Messageable) as an example. In the link, it gives us examples of some Messageable objects, i.e. where you can send messages to, and these are objects such as [`TextChannel`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.TextChannel)s, [`Member`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Member)s etc.

Occasionally I see someone miss out an `await` or not know when to add them, or add them too often. You'll know when to add one, as the docs will state whether the function is a couroutine or not, for example:

[image]

That's how you know what you can do with each object - think of these as templates for the objects you get within discord, not something that you define!

If you need any further clarification or if you noticed any mistakes with my answer, please let me know.

---

**References:**

- [`commands.Command()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.command) - decorator for commands
- [`commands.Context`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#context)
- [Coroutines](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#coroutines)
- [`discord.Member`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Member)
- [`Member.roles`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Member.roles)
- [`discord.Role`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Role)
- [`Context.send()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Context.send)
- [`discord.TextChannel`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.TextChannel)
- [`discord.utils`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#utility-functions)
- [`discord.abc`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#abstract-base-classes)

Comment: I like this a lot, I will start redirecting people to this comment, if they ask me about a quick start to the library :)

Comment: @LuM Oh ghee that's a lot of pressure haha, but honestly I'm really happy you think that, thank you! If at any point you want to add something or feel as though I've worded anything incorrectly/been misleading, please go ahead and change it! Thanks again :')