# Is there a command that I can use to send messages to other people in discord rewrite?

Tags: python, discord.py

My discord commands for users to use is  `/dm @differentuser <message>`.

What command line could I use to send a direct message to a specific member?

I know there is `author = ctx.message.author` and `await author.send(msg)`.

Comment: Also, please only add the necessary tags, as then people will know specifically which language to answer with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do is add an argument which the command will see as a member object, like so:

```py
@bot.command()
async def dm(ctx, member: discord.Member, *, message):
    await member.send(message)
    await ctx.send(":white_check_mark: Sent!")
```

Bear in mind that this will throw a [`Forbidden`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Forbidden) error if the bot wasn't able to send the message. This could be either because the member has blocked the bot or they're not accepting DMs from that server, as per the privacy settings.

---

**References:**

- [`discord.Member`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Member)
- [`Member.send()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Member.send)
- [`Messageable.send()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.abc.Messageable.send) - `discord.Member` inherits from this. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61869972/how-to-define-objects-in-discord-py-rewrite/61872572#61872572) for how Messageables work.