# Discord.py get custom status

Tags: python, discord

How to get the Discord user custom status through discord.py?

I've seen the discord.py documentation. And the only thing I could find is [`Member.status`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=status#discord.Member.status)
Which returns the status as: online / offline / idle / dnd.

But not the new custom status value.
I'm also not searching for the custom presence.

Comment: Have you tried the developer portal?https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/gateway#presence-update-presence-update-event-fields

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you're after is a `CustomActivity`.

As explained by in the docs, a user can have multiple activities, but try this out for size:

```
@bot.command()
async def mycustomstatus(ctx):
    for s in ctx.author.activities:
        if isinstance(s, discord.CustomActivity):
            await ctx.send(s)
```

**On a slightly related note: Please bear in mind that bots [cannot set custom activities](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/issues/2400) as of the time of writing this answer; only read them.**

---

**EDIT:**
If you can't get a member's activity, make sure you have enabled privileged intents:

```
import discord

intents = discord.Intents().all()
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=..., intents=intents)
```

And from your bot's application page:
[image]

---

### References:

- [`Member.activities`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=status#discord.Member.activities)
- [`discord.CustomActivity`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=status#discord.CustomActivity)
- [`isinstance()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance) - Python builtin
- [Privileged intents](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intents.html?#privileged-intents)

Comment: `discord.Member.activity` always returns `None`

Comment: @Aaron That's because you need an *instance* of a member, not just the member object. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61869972/how-to-define-objects-in-discord-py-rewrite) for more info.

Comment: I got both intents on, and are using this: `activities = (await guild.fetch_member(user.id)).activities`. This still returns `()`

Comment: @Aaron Try using `activities = guild.get_member(user.id).activities` instead.