# Discord.py check custom status

Tags: python, discord.py

Do you know if we can check the custom status of members ? I want to add role at all members with the link of the discord on their custom status, is this possible ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Discord.py get custom status](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65596424/discord-py-get-custom-status)

Answer (score 0):

This will check the all activities (game, spotify e.t.c) of a member and catch the custom if exist.

```
for activity in member.activities:
    if isinstance(activity, discord.CustomActivity):
        #doing something
```

Comment: This could be shortend by using
https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.utils.get

Comment: You also need to enable the presence intent

Comment: Perfect ! Thanks to everyone for your help !