# Is there a Discord.py function that i can use that will read a members custom status?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm in the process of creating a python based discord bot that a verification process when joining, and I was wanting to make an automatic function that when the member either joins or is already in the server, to read their custom status message and if it detects banned words to which I can add in a database for it to remove all roles and give certain roles like a quarantine feature.

Would anyone know of any function or method I can use to do this ?
cheers

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Discord.py get custom status](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65596424/discord-py-get-custom-status)

Answer (score -1):

I think what you are after are `CustomActivity`.

**Just remember u cant change the custom status just view them!**

```
@bot.command()
async def mycustomstatus(ctx):
    for s in ctx.author.activities:
        if isinstance(s, discord.CustomActivity):
            await ctx.send(s)
```

Comment: If you've flagged a question as a duplicate, you shouldn't answer with the answer from the duplicate question. Flag and move on.